# How $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|x|}{(1+x^{2n})^{\frac{1}{n}}}=\frac{1}{|x|}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{(1+\frac{1}{2^n})^{\frac{1}{n}}}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Show that $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{1+x^{2n}}$, for $x\in\mathbb{R}$.
>
> Resolution: For $|x|>1$. Applying the root rest $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|x|}{(1+x^{2n})^{\frac{1}{n}}}=\frac{1}{|x|}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{(1+\frac{1}{2^n})^{\frac{1}{n}}}=\frac{1}{|x|}$

I tried to divide both in the numerator and in the denominator by $\frac{1}{|x|}$ but it does not deliver the result.

**Question:**

How does the author go from $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|x|}{(1+x^{2n})^{\frac{1}{n}}}$to$\frac{1}{|x|}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{(1+\frac{1}{2^n})^{\frac{1}{n}}}$ ?

Comment: And naturally, you know how to prove that, for $|x|>1$, $\left(1+\frac1{x^{2n}}\right)^{1/n}\to1$?

Comment: Five days later...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is a typo with $2^n$ instead of $x^{2n}$, indeed note that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|x|}{(1+x^{2n})^{\frac{1}{n}}}=\frac{1}{|x|}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^2}{(1+x^{2n})^{\frac{1}{n}}}=\frac{1}{|x|}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{(1+\frac{1}{x^{2n}})^{\frac{1}{n}}}=\frac{1}{|x|}$$

Comment: Thanks for you answer! But I still cannot see how you go from $\frac{1}{|x|}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^2}{(1+x^{2n})^{\frac{1}{n}}}$ to $\frac{1}{|x|}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{(1+\frac{1}{x^{2n}})^{\frac{1}{n}}}$? Do you divide by $x^2$ both on the numerator and the denominator?

Comment: @PedroGomes Exactly, I can add this step if it not clear!